Unity zombie game shooting system problem
I have a zombie game in Unity. In this game, I kill zombies by shooting at the point I click on the screen with the mouse, but sometimes even though the raycast hits the zombie, the zombie is not affected and when I control it, I get the tag and name values ​​of the object behind the zombie. How can I solve this problem? I am using the following line of code. EnabledLayer selections match the zombie collider layers, there is no problem in that part.
public void FireEvent()
    {
        if (!fireAuth)
            return;

        if (GameManager_PTH.Instance.IsGameStart)
        {
            Vector3 getMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            if (MermiBar.mermiIndex > 0)
            {
                currentDelay = TriggerDelay;
                Ray ray = RaycastCamera.ScreenPointToRay(getMousePos);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, MaxDistance, EnabledLayer))
                {
                    Debug.LogError("What did I hit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag(HittableTag))
                    {
                        Zombie_PTH zombie =       hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Zombie_PTH>();
                        string name = hit.collider.gameObject.name.Trim();

                        if (name.Contains("HeadCollider"))
                            zombie.HitYedim(HitType.Kafa, getMousePos);
                        else if (name.Contains("BodyCollider"))
                            zombie.HitYedim(HitType.Govde, getMousePos);
                        else if (name.Contains("ArmCollider"))
                            zombie.HitYedim(HitType.Govde, getMousePos);
                        else if (name.Contains("LegCollider"))
                            zombie.HitYedim(HitType.Govde, getMousePos);

                        Instantiate(BloodParticle, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
                    }
                }

                StopAllCoroutines();
                StartCoroutine(SightPosition());
                MermiBar.Shot();

                Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * MaxDistance, Color.green, 0.25f);
                SoundSFX_PTH.Instance.PlaySound(SoundSFX_PTH.ClipModel.GUN, 0, 1, false);
            }
            else
            {
                //RELOAD SOUND
                SoundSFX_PTH.Instance.PlaySound(SoundSFX_PTH.ClipModel.SOUND_EFFECT, 3, 1, false);
            }
        }
    }

EnabledLayer selections match the zombie collider layers, there is no problem in that part.

Related.

Using string comparisons like you are is not very reliable and means that changing the name of the objects forces you to change the code every time. Regardless, this should work if everything is set up correctly which we cannot see here. Please show us the hierarchy of the zombie prefab as well as any other relevant configurations for this system.
